# jQuery/ajax - Loading external Div's

Tags: jquery, ajax

Here I have the page already loaded... it hides until clicked. Once clicked the external page is triggered, opens and displayed dynamic content.

The problem is it's grabbing too much of the page... I only need the contents of 1 div... not the whole page...

help please... here's the code..

```
(function($){ 
    $.am_get_item = function (item_id, size_id){
        $.ajax({ url: "/order/item/" + item_id + "/" + size_id, success: function(data){
            $(".item_form").hide();
            $("#form_" + item_id).html(data);
            /* $("#form_" + item_id).load("/order/item/" + item_id + "/" + size_id + "#show_item"); */
            $("#form_" + item_id).slideDown("slow");
            $("input#form1").keyup(function () {var value = $(this).val();$("div#ok").text(value);}).keyup();
        }});        
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: @user: To "accept" an answer means to click the large checkmark to the left of the most helpful answer (if any). You can review [your previous questions](http://stackoverflow.com/users/154107/user154107#questions-table) and accept answers to them.

Comment: thx... now can we answer the one above please.. jQuery/ajax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#form_" + item_id).each(function() {
   $(this).html(data);
   var div = $(this).find("div_i_want_selector").clone();
   $(this).empty().append(div);
   $(this).slideDown("slow");
});
```

Comment: the answer was.. <pre><code>$(data).find("#show_item").appendTo("#form_" + item_id);</code></pre> thanks for the hint...

Answer (score 0):

from http://api.jquery.com/load/

> Loading Page Fragments
>
> The .load() method, unlike $.get(),
>   allows us to specify a portion of the
>   remote document to be inserted. This
>   is achieved with a special syntax for
>   the url parameter. If one or more
>   space characters are included in the
>   string, the portion of the string
>   following the first space is assumed
>   to be a jQuery selector that
>   determines the content to be loaded.

So, basically, use load() function and add the specific div selector at the end of the url.